# Merge Results in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

```
ID    THINGS    QTY     PRICE
123   bag        1       25
123   shoes      1       10
123   pen        1       40
123   dress      1       20
```

The result in my report:
I put all the fields in sub_reports under group footer

```
bag     25x1    25
shoes   10x1    10
pen     40x1    40
dress   20x1    20
```

How can I merge them resulting to:

```
Materials  95x4    95
```

Can you help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far with your merge? try show your code so someone can help fix it.

Comment: take summary in report footer

Comment: Where report footer in main report or in sub report?

Comment: Added summary in report footer in the main report and it works thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As Siva suggested, you should probably have a Group created using your ID field, then Insert summary fields for sum(price) and sum(quantity) at the ID group. This will insert totals for both at the group footer

Comment: If I summarize the price and the quantity will the label (the Things) be summarize too?

Comment: They will be summarized together regardless of the "things" field this way.

If you want a total for each and one for all materials, group both ID and "things"